# Read content of cert.pem in ionic 7

Tags: http, ionic-framework, ionic7

I would want to read the content of pem.cert stored in the asset folder. However when I read, it keeps returning error JSON parse error: invalid number.

```
async loadData():Promise<Observable<{}>>{
   const filePath = '/assets/' + this.pemCertFilePath;
   const certContent = this.http.get(filePath);
   return certContent;
}
```

Called by:

```
let a = (await this.loadData()).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data)
  });
```